# SQL Server providing value for calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run an insert into statement that has a column that requires information from the same statement.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO tblorders (CUST_ID, PRO_ID, QUANTITY, TOTAL)
VALUES (
    (SELECT CUST_ID FROM tblcustomer WHERE EMAIL = 'cwentz@gmail.com'),
    (SELECT PRO_ID FROM tblinventory WHERE PRO_NAME = 'Air Jordan 1'),
    1,
    ((SELECT PRICE FROM tblinventory WHERE PRO_ID = tblorders.PRO_ID) * 1)
);
```

In the last select statement I am trying to get the price of the "Air Jordan 1" by getting the PRO_ID I already selected above it. So I figure that instead of running:

```
((SELECT PRICE FROM tblinventory WHERE PRO_NAME='Air Jordan 1') * 1)
```

which does work, I want to try and get the price based on the PRO_ID that I have already received from this statement:

```
(SELECT PRO_ID FROM tblinventory WHERE PRO_NAME='Air Jordan 1')
```

So is there a way to reference the same table that you are entering data into?

Comment: Ahem, PRICE will be put in the QUANTITY column?  And nothing in the TOTAL column?

Comment: @donPablo I have the number "1" entered for the QUANTITY. The third SELECT is the TOTAL.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected.  Now I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically want a `JOIN` among three tables:

```
INSERT INTO tblorders(CUST_ID, PRO_ID, QUANTITY, TOTAL)
    SELECT c.CUST_ID, i.PRO_ID, o.PRICE
    FROM tblcustomer c JOIN
         tblinventory i
         ON c.EMAIL = 'cwentz@gmail.com' AND i.PRO_NAME = 'Air Jordan 1' JOIN
         tblorders o
         ON i.PRO_ID = o.PRO_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` instead

```
INSERT INTO tblorders(CUST_ID,PRO_ID,QUANTITY,TOTAL)
SELECT 
    (SELECT CUST_ID FROM tblcustomer WHERE EMAIL='cwentz@gmail.com'), 
    PRO_ID, 1 QUANTITY, PRICE
FROM tblinventory WHERE PRO_NAME='Air Jordan 1'
```

`TOP 1` or something like that might be required here.